# Turn a grid an place

Tags: qgis, vector-grid

I have a grid over a rasterlayer and a second a line .file.

I want to place the grid paralell to the line shape or dock it on the shape file.

I tried it with turning the grid manually, but it takes a huge amount of time to fit it correctly.

Is there a way to turn and place this grid?
Maybe there is also a way to genereate the gird directly along the line?

Best, mike[image]

Comment: You could get the azimuth of the line, then use it as an input for the `rotate` tool. Just make sure you set a rotation point outside the grid, otherwise each cell be rotated around itself.

Comment: Thanks! How can i finde the azimuth?

Comment: there's an expression in the field calculator for this.